# Servicestack backend for diferent clients

Tags: servicestack

I am developing an app to serve as a back-end for different clients. Some of the clients are web apps (Vue), some are mobile clients and some are Winforms apps. To keep things DRY and tidy, I want to serve all using Servicestack .Net core. I have some issues regarding the architecture of this app:

One would be that in the documentation it says that is recommended to use POCO's as the DTO, but in order to reuse those POCO's across all apps, they should be in a separate dll, which will conflict with the requirement that all DTOs should be in the same namespace as the services.

What is the best way to organize such a project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have different Apps hosting the same ServiceStack Services then they can all share the same `ServiceModel.dll`.

You can find an example of this in [Hello Mobile Project](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile#servicestack-server-app) which contains an example multiple different ServiceStack hosts sharing the same common libraries, including between [.NET Core and .NET Framework Apps via multi-targeting](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile#shared-gateway).

Comment: I think I was't very clear in my questions. My app will be mainly a Winforms (or WPF) app which will use OrmLite to persist its POCO's to a database. Some of that POCOs will have to be exposed to other apps (mobile) through a Service. I cannot use those POCOs as the DTO, because they will have to be in the ServiceModel.dll, so I will need to create other DTOs for that and convert them?

Comment: @HMihail I still don't understand why you cannot reuse the DTOs in the ServiceModel.dll? The ServiceModel.dll should be dep/impl-free so you should be able to reference it any project, otherwise if you have a reason for keeping it separate you can use a local copy of the class, the [built-in Auto Mapping](https://docs.servicestack.net/auto-mapping) can help with copying properties.

Comment: It was a confusion of mine, I think I cleared that out now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: How would I annotate the POCOs (like `Autoincrement`, etc.) to keep the Servicemodel dep/impl free?

Comment: @HMihail All declarative attributes are defined in the dep/impl-free `ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll` contract assembly which is the only dependency [ServiceModel projects](https://docs.servicestack.net/create-your-first-webservice#step-4-exploring-the-servicestack-solution) should have a reference to.

Comment: So, following up, I am stuck in another situation: I somehow messed up my references, because of too many project types. For me to be able to SelfHost the service (WPF), and call it with JsonServiceClient from both WPF and Android, I should create all shared libraries as .Net Standard, reference only .Core ServiceStack packages in all of them, is that right?

Comment: @HMihail If you need to support both .NET FX and .NET Standard projects you need to multi-target, see the [Shared Gateway](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile#shared-gateway) project for an example which also does this.

Comment: I only need to consume the services from multiple platforms (Winforms, WPF and Android), I will only serve from a SelfHosted WPF app.

Comment: @HMihail If it's only platforms that you can use .NET Framework libs on, you can just use .NET Framework builds, but if you need to use .NET Standard builds anywhere you'd need to multi-target.

Comment: So in my clients (Android, Winforms) which ServiceStack packages should I install, the Core versions or the FX ones?

Comment: You need to at least use the normal FX packages, if you want to use .NET Standard 2.0 dlls in Android you’d need to multi-target otherwise you’d need to use FX builds.